maui: when item in observable collection changes one of its props, UI is not updating unless I leave and reopen page
I am simply trying to catch an item in my observable collection and change one of its props:
   public void Click(object obj)
   {
        Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                var click = obj as WifiSelectionModel;
                if (click == null) return;
                click.IsActive = true;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WifiHotSpots));
        });

My class inherits from : ObservableObject,
If I click, nothing changes in the UI (it should become red).
But if I leave the page and return; the items are now all red. So my logic must be correct, only the way I handle the UI in mvvm seems off.
Any help?
    VM:

public class WifiSelectionModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;
    public int Id {  get; set; }
}

View:
<CollectionView  SelectionMode="Single"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding WifiHotSpots}">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:WifiSelectionModel">
             <Grid Padding="10">
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                     <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                 <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                     <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ClickCommand, Source={x:Reference WifiPageViewPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                 </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                 <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                 <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" IsVisible="{Binding IsActive}" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="1">
                     <Label Text="hi mom"></Label>
                 </StackLayout>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 </CollectionView>


ObservableCollection only updates when items are added or removed.  It does not update when properties on its contained objects are changed

I fixed this by altering my model like this:
public class WifiSelectionModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    private bool _isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set
        {
            if (_isActive != value)
            {
                _isActive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsActive));
            }
        }
    }
    public int Id {  get; set; }
}


Your WifiSelectionModel must also be ObservableObject. ObservableObject implements INotifyPropertyChanged and triggers the PropertyChanged event. Without it, your CollectionView doesn't know that an item has changed.

thank you, some more changes had to me made to my model, see my own answer

From the documentation of ObservableObject:

Simple property
Here's an example of how to implement notification support to a custom property:

private string name;
public string Name
{
    get => name;
    set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
}

I'm not familiar with MAUI, but your WifiSelectionModel.IsActive.set seem to lack anything that informs the UI that it has been changed, and that is likely why changes are ignored. WifiSelectionModel should likely also inherit from ObservableObject, as should every view model used by the UI.
There are multiple different patterns for informing the UI of changes, depending on what framework and libraries are used. But there needs to be something, like raising an event, using an attribute on the property or calling a method.
